# Having issue to validate form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

My following JavaScript is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDetails(search)
    {
    var search = documment.getElementById('query');
    if(search.value ==''||search.value==null)
    {
        alert('No search criteria entered');
        query.focus;
        return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="search" action ="123.php" onSubmit="return checkDetails(this);" method ="get">
    <p><input type ="text" id = "query"  name ="query" /> &nbsp;
    <input type ="submit" value ="Web Service"/></p>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function checkDetails(search)
    {
        var search = document.getElementById('query');
        if(search.value ===''||search.value===null)
        {
            alert('No search criteria entered');
            search.focus();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

You wrote docu**mm**ent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify in what way it's not working - you get an error, it doesn't validate correctly, you don't get the error alert?  One thing I spotted:

```
query.focus;
```

Should be

```
search.focus();
```

Also you misspelled document as documment

Answer (score 0):

It will be

```
search.focus();
```

instead of

```
query.focus;
```

and `documment` will be `document`

Answer (score 0):

Also try something like this

```
onSubmit="return checkDetails(this,this.id);"

function checkDetails(search,id)
    {
    var search = documment.getElementById(id);
    if(search.value ==''||search.value==null)
    {
        alert('No search criteria entered');
        query.focus;
        return false;
        }
    }
```